# Encrypting data using AES

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I do not know much about encrypting. I am trying to use authenticate user information to save data to the binary file which is decrypted/encrypted using AES (commonly used encryption algorithm as of 2011).

How would I begin?

I have a piece of code which let me to authenticate the user:

```
using System;

namespace Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes
{
    class AuthenticateUser
    {
        private string userName, password;

        public AuthenticateUser(string userName, string password)
        {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return userName;
            }
            set
            {
                userName = value;
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return password;
            }
            set
            {
                password = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For details including sample source on how to encrypt/decrypt in C# via AES .NET already several things built-in see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx

IF you are more interested in how all the bits work algorithmically take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164055.aspx

Other interesting links/source code:

- http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/encrypt-and-decrypt-strings-SID205.aspx
- http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156922-aes-encryption-and-c%23/

Comment: Ok. I do see the example. But I have never user 'using' as method. Is there anything from basics if this?

Comment: `using` helps with avoiding leaks... for some details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx